# Return all values as an array after the map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to write to the array the value of each `sum` of all the `reports`.

```
month: donate_report.report[0].reports[0].sum
```

Unfortunately, this function returns an empty array:

```
month: donate_report.report[0].reports;
const doubles = month.map(function (elem) {
                    return elem.sum;
                });
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance

```
"reports": [
        {
           "id": 1,
          "sum": 5221,
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "sum": 5421,
        }
]
```

Comment: post the full array

Comment: posted an array from which I need to take data

Comment: That's not a complete data structure. Please provide the outer level also so that it represents valid JavaScript notation.

Comment: month returns exactly this structure, no problem with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure you provided was not complete or wrong. Considering it as a object you can use map and return the sum property

```js
var a={"reports": [
        {
           "id": 1,
          "sum": 5221,
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "sum": 5421,
        }
]}
const doubles=a.reports.map((e)=>e.sum);
console.log(doubles)
```